# UI not detecting observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

Hi guys i have a strange problem with KO Observable array and my UI ,if i pass a fixed model to my observable array this one works ! and show the select options correctly but if make this one dynamically simply not show anything, i already made a first one  select option to be dynamically working and it works perfect!, but the second option simply does not work.

Here are the code of my model for the options

```
var TipoModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
   self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var HabitacionModel = function(Huespedes) {
...
self.loadRoomsType = function() {
    ajax("/api/foro/loadrooms", {}, function(data) {

        self.tipoHabitacion = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.each(data, function(index, habitacion) {
            var hab = new TipoModel({
                id: habitacion.id,
                name: habitacion.nombreHabitacion
            });
            self.tipoHabitacion.push(hab);
        });
    }, "GET");
    console.log(self.tipoHabitacion());
}
self.loadpartnersType = function() {
    ajax("/api/foro/loadpartners", {}, function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.tipoHuesped = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.each(data, function(index, socio) {

            var x = new TipoModel({
                id: socio.id,
                name: socio.nombre
            });

            self.tipoHuesped.push(x);
        });
        console.log(self.tipoHuesped());

    }, "GET");
}
```

the load rooms work but the parters function is not working and is the same code only a few changes but its the same .

```
<select style="width:30%; height:100%; margin-top:4px; background-color:transparent; border-color:#729A2B;" data-bind="options: tipoHuesped,
                        value: selectedHuesped,
                        optionsText: 'name', 
                        optionsValue: 'id',
                       optionsCaption: 'Escoge...'" required></select>
```

if i define like this the observable array from the start it works

```
self.tipoHuesped = ko.observableArray([
    new TipoModel({
        id: "1",
        name: "Aeroméxico"
    }),
    new TipoModel({
        id: "2",
        name: "Magnicharters"
    })
]);
```

i want to make this dynamically cause more data will be added soon, hope u can help me guys. 
Thanks

Comment: "self.tipoHabitacion = ko.observableArray([]);" should not be inside ajax callback - you create a new instance of the observableArray, but markup is aleady bound to previous one.

Comment: the same thing is with "self.tipoHuesped = ko.observableArray([]);"

Answer (score 2):

"self.tipoHabitacion = ko.observableArray([]);" should not be inside ajax callback - you create a new instance of the observableArray, but markup is aleady bound to previous one.

So you should create observables once a time, and then add or remove items to/from them:

```
var TipoModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
   self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var HabitacionModel = function(Huespedes) {
...
self.tipoHabitacion = ko.observableArray([]);
self.tipoHuesped = ko.observableArray([]);
self.loadRoomsType = function() {
    ajax("/api/foro/loadrooms", {}, function(data) {

        self.tipoHabitacion.removeAll();
        $.each(data, function(index, habitacion) {
            var hab = new TipoModel({
                id: habitacion.id,
                name: habitacion.nombreHabitacion
            });
            self.tipoHabitacion.push(hab);
        });
    }, "GET");
    console.log(self.tipoHabitacion());
}
self.loadpartnersType = function() {
    ajax("/api/foro/loadpartners", {}, function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.tipoHuesped.removeAll();
        $.each(data, function(index, socio) {

            var x = new TipoModel({
                id: socio.id,
                name: socio.nombre
            });

            self.tipoHuesped.push(x);
        });
        console.log(self.tipoHuesped());

    }, "GET");
}
```

Comment: i already implement this code but it give me an error of Cannot read property 'push' of undefined , i implement the var self for the observables arrray , am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: already works only add a brackets in the observable but something curious happend , self.tipoHabitacion().push(hab); works perfect, but self.tipoHuesped().push(x); returns an error of element not found even this one its being initialized in the main object

Comment: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" message means that observable array is not created at this moment - your function is called before array is initialized.

Comment: self.tipoHabitacion().push(hab); - is not good because thus you modify the stored array, not observable collection. this leads that subscribers will not be notified about collection changed.

Comment: If you can create jsfiddle or SO code snippet, I can check it

Comment: i already realize whats all about it , didn`t realize the code was separated in objects, so i was trying to append the piece of code to the wrong object!

Answer (score 0):

i already realize whats all about it , didn`t realize the code was separated in objects, so i was trying to append the piece of code to the wrong object!

I`m getting started with ko so didn`t realize about all this !
Apologies to all !